# how to make left join on two tables in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, database, laravel, left-join

These are my two table's as:

**company_industry_type:**

[image]

**law_master**:
[image]

table company_industry_type has columns lm_id that is assigned to particular id.

i want to fetch the lm_id and law_name from **table law_master** 
with respect to the lm_id assigned to id of **table company_industry_type**

please help me with this, i'm new to laravel.

```
<?php
  $law = DB::table('tbl_company_industry_type')->pluck('lm_id');
  $law_d = DB::table('tbl_law_master')->whereIn('id',$law)
           ->select('id','lm_id','law_name')->get();
           $res_lms = '';
           foreach($law_d as $law_details)
           {
           ?>
           <span id="sublaw_data">{{ $law_details->lm_id }} 
           ({{ $law_details->law_name }}) <i class="fa fa-remove deleteclass" 
           onclick="delete_law('<?php echo $law_details->id?>')"></i></span>
           <?php
           $res_lms .=$law_details->id.",";
           }
           $res_lawids=trim($res_lms,',');
?>
```

my code returns only one id's data i.e 1 and not for 3,4 for last record of 
company_industry_type

Comment: Could you please add your sample data as text?

Comment: I dont understand what your lm_id is doing in: company_industry_type table...

Comment: You need a match for it to join. Example `law_master.lm_id` would = `company_industry_type.lm_id` yet it doesn't.

Comment: Try using [one-to-many eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). It will make your life much simpler.

Comment: @rudolf_franek can you please check my code and correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Using below query you can get result as per your requirements.

DB::table('company_industry_type')
            ->join('company_industry_type', 'company_industry_type.lm_id', '=', 'law_master.lm_id')
            ->select('law_master.lm_id', 'law_master.law_name', 'company_industry_type.*')
            ->get();